# Como Agregar Onclicked a Button que se Crea desde xaml.cs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarinforms

```
var footers = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, Padding = new Thickness(10) };
        footers.Children.Add(new Button()
        {
            Text = "Guardar",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#BB0032"),
            CornerRadius = 5,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            FontSize = 20,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            ClassId = "btnGuardarEstimaciones"
        });
```

intente agregarlo en esta parte donde termina la creacion del boton
new Button(){
}.Clicked ( pero no se como implementarlo al 100 )

Answer (score 0):

Ya Encontre la Solucion ( texto en negritas ) :

```
footers.Children.Add(new Button(){
            Text = "Guardar Estimaciones",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#BB0032"),
            CornerRadius = 5,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            FontSize = 20,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            ClassId = "btnGuardarEstimaciones",
            **Command = new Command(() => {
                GuardarEstimacionesMoveToTerminoSiniestro();
            })**

        });
```